# How to remove pair-wise comparisons that are affected by a batch covariate in pairwise Wilcoxon test

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, confounding, batch-normalization

I have a dependent variable that is grouped by an independent.variable (with 3 factor levels) and I want to calculate pairwise comparisons between the groups of the independent.variable. However, I noticed a second variable is confounding the results (confounding.variable).

Here is an example:

```
dat<-structure(list(independent.variable=c("A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","C"),confounding.variable=c("batch-1","batch-1","batch-1","batch-1","batch-1","batch-2","batch-2","batch-2","batch-2","batch-2","batch-2","batch-2"),dependent.variable=c(0.2,0.1,-2.5,-2,-1.7,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.4)),row.names=c(268L,225L,75L,4L,288L,230L,231L,232L,280L,297L,270L,271L),class="data.frame")
```

I can see there is a difference between group A and B, and B and C

```
boxplot(dat$dependent.variable ~ dat$independent.variable)
```

[image]

Which is confirmed with the K-S and Wilcoxon test:

```
kruskal.test(dat$dependent.variable ~ as.factor(dat$independent.variable))
```

kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 8.2292, df = 2, p-value = 0.01633

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(dat$dependent.variable, as.factor(dat$independent.variable))

data:  dat$dependent.variable and as.factor(dat$independent.variable) 

A    B    B 0.08 -    C 0.50 0.08
```

However, this result is also confounded with batch:

```
boxplot(dat$dependent.variable ~ dat$confounding.variable)
```

[image]

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(dat$dependent.variable , as.factor(dat$confounding.variable))

     batch-1 batch-2 p = 0.0041
```

1. Is there a way to account for this confounding variable in the pairwise comparison?
2. In less clear cut cases, how could one quantify the extent a confounding variable has on the means between groups?

Comment: How do you know this is a confounder? What is batch?

Comment: In my setting (omics data) the variable I called batch, is such a variable that is known to introduce a technical source of variation. For example, all values in batch-1 are lower than in batch-2, and it is know a priori these differences are purely technical and should be corrected for. In some cases, I do not know which variable is confounding, but let's assume in this case it is know.

Comment: A generalized linear model could take care of the batch as a random effect.